# how to add 90 days to expiry date or subtract 90 days from system date

Tags: c#

now just add 90 days with expiry date or subtract 90 days from system date. it will solve my problem! i want that the row color is red when 90 days left to item expiry date

```
 private void DgvStock_CellFormatting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvStock.Rows)
            {

                DateTime exp = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["ExpDate"].Value);

                if (exp <= System.DateTime.Now)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ....and what's not working for you? have tried something? have you looked at the functionality that `DateTime` provides?

Comment: Do not process all the rows in that event - your app will seem sluggish and slow with more than a few rows of data.  The event arguments tell you which row needs to be formatted

Answer (score 1):

to add or substract days from current date you can do like this:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90);
```

[image]

and change you code like:

```
if (exp <= System.DateTime.Now)
{
    row.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    row.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
else
{
    row.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    row.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;       // or some other origin color
}
```

looks like you using `DefaultCellStyle` incorrectly. `DefaultCellStyle` change style for all rows, but you need to change colors for specific row.

Comment: @SaudKhan as you can see 3 similar answer was provided by 3 different developers with high reputation. I am sure that problem in your usage if this function. Just quick example (see attached image in my anser)

Comment: looks like you using `DefaultCellStyle` incorrectly. `DefaultCellStyle` change style for all rows, but you need to change colors for specific row. See my changes in answer. I don't remember exactly how to change styles in WinForms grid, so you need to find it by your self, but don't use `DefaultCellStyle`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (exp <= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))
{
    //...
```

P.S: I would move the DateTime.Now outside the loop and save it into a variable once.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvStock.Rows)
        {
            DateTime exp = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["ExpDate"].Value + "");


            if (exp <= System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90))
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {

                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: when i write this as all row colors change to red in datagrid view      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DgvStock.Rows)
            {

                DateTime ExpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["ExpDate"].Value);
                if (ExpDate >= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }

            }

Comment: DateTime ExpDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["ExpDate"].Value);
                if (ExpDate >= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))

Comment: if condition like that   if (ExpDate <= System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90))

Comment: it change all row color to red